# Factory Pattern - Type variables

Tags: java, enums, factory-pattern

First, my english is not the best and I haven't found what I was looking for, maybe because I didn't knew how to ask google in english or my nativ language > java beginner!

I am developing a little game where I use many types of "bombs", for this I am using an abstract class `Bomb` and an enum `BombType`. Each type of bomb should have its own values, for example a `range`and a `timer`. Now I am struggling with the bussiness logic how I should use bombs and how I should handle their types. Is it better to make use of their `type` or their `class`?

What I have:

```
public enum BombType {

    // pass object or what else?
    DEFAULT(new Default()),
    NUKE(new Nuke());

    public final int range;
    public final long timer;

    BombType(Bomb paramBomb) {
        this.range = paramBomb.range;
        this.timer = paramBomb.timer;
    }
}

public abstract class Bomb {

    final BombType bombType;
    final int range;
    final long timer;

    protected Bomb(BombType paramBombType) {
        this.bombType = paramBombType;
        this.range = paramBombType.range;
        this.timer = paramBombType.timer;
    }

}

public class Default extends Bomb {
    protected Default() {
        super(BombType.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

**So my question is how should I handle the different types of bombs in the outter world?**

**Option 1, by class:**

```
public void doSomethingWithTheBomb(Bomb bomb) {
    switch(bomb.bombType) {
        case DEFAULT: 
            Default defaultBomb = (Default) bomb;
            logger.log(defaultBomb.range);
            logger.log(defaultBomb.timer);
            {...}
            break;
        case NUKE: 
            Nuke nukeBomb = (Nuke) bomb;
            logger.log(nukeBomb.range);
            logger.log(nukeBomb.timer);
            {...}
            break;
        defrault:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Option 2, by type:**

```
public void doSomethingWithTheBomb(Bomb bomb) {
    logger.log(bomb.bombType.range);
    logger.log(bomb.bombType.timer);
    {...}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 is bad, since you duplicate code.
Option 2 is better.

I would add a `getRange()` and `getTimer()` to the abstract Bomb class, and depending obn what needs to be done, a `doSomething()` method. That way you can have your Bomb (whichever it is) do something.

Comment: so the enum `BombType` doesn't need to know the bomb type specific range or timer rigth?

Comment: correct. You could have a constructor in your Bomb class, that takes the range and timer as parameters.

Comment: Okay so is there a better way than passing > 5 parameters to the constructor? Like passing the class or what else and accessing the class its values `range` and `timer`?

Comment: That is way too broad a question and is also opinion-based. I don't mind a constructor with many parameters, but prefer methods with at most 2 parameters. There are patterns to initialize the object without having them in the constructor IIRC.

Comment: Okay then I have to read and practise more! Thank you very much!